# MySQL equivalent to Oracle's "describe_procedure"

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures

Is there an equivalent to Oracle's describe_procedure (which returns resultset of all parameters) for MySQL?

I'm aware of the mysql.proc table that has a param_list attribute storing a comma separated string attribute of params "param_list".  However, I'd be interested to see if there was an equivalent to the describe_procedure of Oracle?

Comment: "describe_procedure" isn't SQL Server... you mean Oracle?

Comment: Thanks gbn for pointing that out. Have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes :-

```
show create procedure $PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

docs:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html